# Passing array of PL/SQL object to JAVA stored procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to achieve something that looks like a simple task.

I found in oracle a very helpful guide that demonstrate how to do something
very similar to what i'm looking for: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64686/04_call1.htm

This code taken from the guide:

PL/SQL code:

define the object:

```
CREATE TYPE Employee AS OBJECT (
  empno    NUMBER(4),
  ename    VARCHAR2(10),
  job      VARCHAR2(9),
  mgr      NUMBER(4),
  hiredate DATE,
  sal      NUMBER(7,2),
  comm     NUMBER(7,2),
  deptno   REF Department
);
```

Now, create the table object that will hold objects of type Employee:

```
CREATE TABLE emps OF Employee AS
SELECT Employee(e.empno, e.ename, e.job, e.mgr, e.hiredate, e.sal,
e.comm, (SELECT REF(d) FROM depts d WHERE d.deptno = e.deptno))
FROM emp e;
```

Create the java stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_sal (e IN OUT Employee, r NUMBER)
AS LANGUAGE JAVA 
NAME 'Paymaster.raiseSal(Paymaster[], java.math.BigDecimal)';
```

Now, the java class:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import oracle.oracore.*;
import oracle.jdbc2.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Paymaster implements SQLData {
  // Implement the attributes and operations for this type.
  private BigDecimal empno;
  private String ename;
  private String job;
  private BigDecimal mgr;
  private Date hiredate;
  private BigDecimal sal;
  private BigDecimal comm;
  private Ref dept;

  public static void raiseSal(Paymaster[] e, BigDecimal amount) {
    e[0].sal =               // IN OUT passes [0]
     e[0].sal.add(amount);  // increase salary by given amount
  }
```

So far so good.

What i'm looking for is not to send not only one struct to raiseSal, but an array of structs by **reference**, so i will be able to iterate over all the objects and work with them. I want to send the **entire table** and change it in real time inside the java class.

I looked for a solution for a long time but i only found solutions for the other way around: connect to PL/SQL stored procedure and get the array. I don't want any database connections in my class, because many DBs will be using this class. It should be portable.

Is it even possible?

If so, i'll be happy if an example of how to call **raiseSal** from PL/SQL with the table.

When going over the guide i saw that that **TABLE, VARRAY** SQL types have corresponding **oracle.sql.ARRAY,  oracle.jdbc2.Array** java types. Can it be used to solve my problem?

Thank you for your help!